# Почему в даггер2 при использовании @Singleton экземпяр всегда создается new?

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Имеется объект

```
public  class RxUtilsAbs {
   @Inject
   public RxUtilsAbs(Context context){}

}
```

В статьях по даггер 2 пишут, что нужно создать модуль, который будет провайдить объект `RxUtilsAbs`. Но как я заметил, что если этот модуль создать и передать его компоненту, то в генерируется код, который пользуется этим модулем для предоставления объекта `RxUtilsAbs`. Если, этот модуль предоставляет каждый раз новый объект, то так и будет. Если он предоставляет один и тот же инстанс, то теряется логика..зачем тогда вообще дагер нужен. Зачастую нам нужны именно синглтоны.

Если же такой модуль не будет создан (о чем я не видел ни в одной статье), то даггер 2 проверит, есть ли у него, то что нужно для инициализации этого объекта. А нужен ему в данном случае `Context`. И если есть модуль, который провайдит контекст или контекст был передан при создании `Builder` , то в сгенируется такой код

```
public RxUtilsAbs rxUtilsAbs() {
    return new RxUtilsAbs(provideContextProvider.get());
  }
```

Т.е. напрашивается вывод, что эти модули не нужны. Даггер итак сам разбирается, что куда добавить, чтобы создать экземпляр требуемого объекта.

```
@Module
public class UtilsModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public RxUtilsAbs provideRxUtilsAbs(Context context) {
        return new RxUtilsAbs(context);
    }  
}
```

Единственное отличие, в том что в модуле `provideRxUtilsAbs(Context context)` помечен как синглтон. Это, как я понимаю, означало, что будет всегда даггером возвращаться один и тот же экземпляр класса. Но как я указал выше в сгенерированном коде, хоть я и создаю модуль , хоть не создаю, всегда `new` экземпляр.

Почему так? Как в разных классах получать один и тот же экземпляр?

**UPD**

```
Component(modules = {AppModule.class, DataModule.class, UtilsModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {

    Context context();
    IDateRepository iDateRepository();
    RxUtilsAbs rxUtilsAbs();


}
```

И вот я передаю контекст `Application`

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent appComponent;
    private ChatComponent chatComponent;

    public static   AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = buildAppComponent();
    }

    AppComponent buildAppComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Есть еще один зависимый компонент и там тоже обозначен контекст..может в этом проблема

```
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
@ChatScope
public interface ChatComponent {

    Context context();
    ChatInteract iChatInteract();

}
```

Comment: Может быть у вас разные экземпляры компонента и поэтому получаете для каждого свою копию синглтона?

Comment: А какой контекст вы передаете при инициализации ?

Comment: сперва хотел бы ответить на свой же вопрос насчет того, что модули не нужны. Сегодня мне компилятор сам сказал, что эти модули излишне, пометил их как депрекейтед и дал ссылку на https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules . У меня есть связанные  с этим вопросы, но их надо расписывать в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: Вот добавил еще код. Но я совершенно запутался. Вот в моем модуле UtilsModule указано, как получить этот экземпляр RxUtilsAbs(context) и  помечен аннотацией синглтон. Генерируемый код ссылается именно на этот метод, но ведь в нем всё время new экземпляр..Мне самому, что ли в этом модуле хранить созданный экземпляр и выдавать именно его, если он не null. Т.е. я сам должен следить за тем, чтобы это был синглтон..тогда зачем нужна это аннотация..я думал увидев его даггер сам сгенерируется нужный код..

Comment: Нашел похожий вопрос , там человек сделал вывод, что надо в модуле явно хранить экземпляр синглтона и аннотацию singleton  можно убрать